# Usage of unofficial Google Reader API on Android

Tags: android, google-reader

I am trying to develop a Google Reader app for Android.
This app was working fine before today with the following code :

```
monTransport = GoogleTransport.create();
GoogleHeaders entete = (GoogleHeaders) monTransport.defaultHeaders;
entete.setApplicationName("ActuXml");
entete.gdataVersion = "2";
entete.setGoogleLogin(jeton);
XmlHttpParser parseur = new XmlHttpParser();
parseur.contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
parseur.namespaceDictionary = NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
monTransport.addParser(parseur);
HttpRequest requete = monTransport.buildGetRequest();
requete.url = new GenericUrl("http://www.google.com/reader/atom/" + finurl);
try {
   flux = requete.execute().parseAs(ReaderItems.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get a valid token by using the android API 2.0 code :

```
AccountManager manageurcomptes = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
Bundle bundle = manageurcomptes.getAuthTokenByFeatures("com.google", AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE,  null, moi,                       null, null, null, null).getResult();
   if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN)) {
    authJeton = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
    util = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
```

Yesterday this code was working, today it doesn't work anymore.
Any change on the server side for the unofficial Google Reader API ?